# Fetch the minimum start_Date and Maximum of End_Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using following query:

```
select * from (Select 


                        [CLIENT_ID],
                        [CLIENT_NAME],
                        [SUPER_GROUP_ID],
                        [SUPER_GROUP],
                        [MASTER_GROUP_ID],
                        [MASTER_GROUP],
                        [SALES_GROUP_ID],
                        [SALES_GROUP],
                        [VOTING_ENTITY_ID], 
                        [VOTING_ENTITY],
                        [COVERAGE_SPECIALITY],
                        [COVERAGE_FUND],
                        [MCM_CLASSIFICATION],
                        [START_DATE],
                        IsNull([END_DATE], GetDate())  as END_DATE,
                        ROW_NUMBER()OVER (partition by CLIENT_ID order by START_DATE desc, END_DATE  ) as RNUM
                FROM [mi_s_data].[dbo].[BI_CLIENT_CONTACT_MAPPING]

                ) CCMAP2
                where CCMAP2.RNUM =1 and ccmap2.CLIENT_ID= '1-12W68I'
```

I want to assign RNUM for that record for which START_DATE is minimum and END_DATE is maximum

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide expected output.

Comment: Please give expected output not only your script.

Answer (score 0):

just change the order for START_DATE and END_DATE, hope this helps

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (partition by CLIENT_ID order by START_DATE, END_DATE desc ) as RNUM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT                            
                             [CLIENT_ID],
                             MIN([START_DATE]) as START_DATE,
                             Max(IsNull([END_DATE], GetDate())) as END_DATE                     
                        FROM [mi_s_data].[dbo].[BI_CLIENT_CONTACT_MAPPING]              

    GROUP BY 
                              [CLIENT_ID]
```